# From sheaf torsors to geometric bundles on schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, rigid-analytic-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}$
$\newcommand{\func}{\mathcal{O}}$
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
It is well known that the notions of locally free $\func_X$-modules on a scheme $X$ and vector bundles on $X$ ($X$-schemes $E$ that are locally $\mathbb{A}_X^n$) are equivalent : given vector bundle, one takes the sheaf of sections, and given a locally free $\func_X$-module $\M$, the total space of the bundle is $\Spec_X(\Sym^\bullet\M^\vee)$.

> Given a group sheme $G$ and a $G$-torsor over $X$, is there a simple procedure that gives the total space of the torsor ?

A few clarifications about the question :

- the general answer seems to be "no", according to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/19432)
- the same link refers to Milne's *Etale cohomology*, section III.4, where a partial answer is given. However it is not what I would call a "simple procedure" : I am looking for something more similar to taking the relative spectrum of the symmetric algebra for a vector bundle.
- however I have no hope that directly taking the relative spectrum of a clever $\func_X$-algebra will work : this is a procedure that "takes closed subschemes", while often a torsor will look like an "open subscheme" (see the following example).

My question is in fact motivated by this particular case : given a locally free $\func_X$-module $\M$, we have the $GL$-torsor of trivializations of $\M$, that is the sheaf whose sections over $U\subset X$ is the set of bases of $\M(U)$ as $\func_X(U)$-module. The question becomes :

> Is there a simple description of the total space of the torsor of trivializations of a vector bundle $\M$ ?

(The point of this, ultimately, is that it will be a final object in the category of couples $(Y,f,\phi)$, where $f\colon Y\to Y$ is a morphism and $\phi$ is an $\func_Y$-isomorphism $f^*\M\simeq\func_Y^n$)

I think this procedure works :

Call $E\to X$ the total space of the bundle $\M$, and form the product $F=E\times_X\ldots\times_XE$ with $n$ terms. By construction, locally over a sufficiently small open $U\subset X$, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}\times U$ (with compatibility between the $U$). We can then take the open subset of points corresponding to an invertible matrix, and this gives the desired space.

What I am interested in is to find a "simpler" way, i.e. using existing general constructions, without needing to manipulating the details like I just did. Admittedly the construction above is not hard in anyway, it just doesn't generalize well.

Last, I feel that this all carries verbatim to rigid analytic geometry (in the sense of Tate), eg the relative spectrum is done by Brian Conrad in *Relative ampleness in rigid geometry* §2.2. But since I am not overly familiar with this setting (especially Grothendieck topologies), I still ask :

> What about the setting of rigid analytic geometry ?

Comment: This is more suitable for mathoverflow and you may transfer it there. I think Brian Conrad may answer most of your questions.